# android textView.setText() gives me null pointer exception

Tags: android

I've create a custom adapter to put images one my listView but is giving me a null pointer exception in my textView.setText(text).

this is the part when i get exception my adapter :

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View rowView = inflater.inflate(rowResourceId, parent, false);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageFileView);
        TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.fileName);

        int pos = position+4;

        String name = Names[pos];

        String extFile = Names[pos].substring(Names[pos].lastIndexOf(".")+1);

        String uri = "drawable/"+extFile+".png";

        textView.setText(name);     

        Uri imgUri=Uri.parse(uri);
        imageView.setImageURI(imgUri);
        return rowView;  
    }
```

this is my LogCat when a i have exception:

```
06-14 12:15:04.616: E/AndroidRuntime(678): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-14 12:15:04.616: E/AndroidRuntime(678): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-14 12:15:04.616: E/AndroidRuntime(678):  at com.example.poc_cubbyhole.ItemAdapter.getView(ItemAdapter.java:59)
06-14 12:15:04.616: E/AndroidRuntime(678):  at android.widget.HeaderViewListAdapter.getView(HeaderViewListAdapter.java:220)
06-14 12:15:04.616: E/AndroidRuntime(678):  at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1430)
06-14 12:15:04.616: E/AndroidRuntime(678):  at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1745)
06-14 12:15:04.616: E/AndroidRuntime(678):  at android.widget.ListView.fillSpecific(ListView.java:1290)
06-14 12:15:04.616: E/AndroidRuntime(678):  at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1588)
06-14 12:15:04.616: E/AndroidRuntime(678):  at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1260)
06-14 12:15:04.616: E/AndroidRuntime(678):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
06-14 12:15:04.616: E/AndroidRuntime(678):  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:912)
06-14 12:15:04.616: E/AndroidRuntime(678):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
06-14 12:15:04.616: E/AndroidRuntime(678):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
06-14 12:15:04.616: E/AndroidRuntime(678):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
06-14 12:15:04.616: E/AndroidRuntime(678):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1254)
06-14 12:15:04.616: E/AndroidRuntime(678):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1130)
06-14 12:15:04.616: E/AndroidRuntime(678):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1047)
06-14 12:15:04.616: E/AndroidRuntime(678):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
06-14 12:15:04.616: E/AndroidRuntime(678):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
06-14 12:15:04.616: E/AndroidRuntime(678):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
06-14 12:15:04.616: E/AndroidRuntime(678):  at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1140)
06-14 12:15:04.616: E/AndroidRuntime(678):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1859)
06-14 12:15:04.616: E/AndroidRuntime(678):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-14 12:15:04.616: E/AndroidRuntime(678):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-14 12:15:04.616: E/AndroidRuntime(678):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
06-14 12:15:04.616: E/AndroidRuntime(678):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-14 12:15:04.616: E/AndroidRuntime(678):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
06-14 12:15:04.616: E/AndroidRuntime(678):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
06-14 12:15:04.616: E/AndroidRuntime(678):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
06-14 12:15:04.616: E/AndroidRuntime(678):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

this is xml file that create items in my listView :

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageFileView"
            android:layout_width="32dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="9dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>
    <TextView
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/fileName"
            android:layout_width="97dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="66dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"/>
```

and this is my listView :

```
<com.example.poc_cubbyhole.widgets.PullToRefreshListView
    android:id="@+id/list_files"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button_upload"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
    />
```

i use a widget to change add the pull and refresh to my listView

Comment: make sure you have `fileName` id in `rowResourceId` layout and check `name`  value

Comment: plz check your if(rootView==null) View rowView = inflater.inflate(rowResourceId, parent, false);

Comment: post logcat exception

Comment: paste 54 line of your  item adapter.

Comment: line 59 is : textView.setText(name)

Comment: replace rowResourceId with your file list layout like R.layout.list_listlayout

Comment: `textView` or `name is null as i said in first comment, post layout of this listItem

Comment: nothing change, it's giving me a null pointer exception

Comment: Add this at the second line of getview-->View rowView=convertView;
  if(rowView==null)
  {//your work
  }

Comment: i edit my post by adding xml files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this

```
TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.fileName);
```

to

```
TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
```

in your `getView` method,Because your `TextView` Id is `textView` not `fileName`

Comment: @yassine__ Happy to help,StackOverflow answer all problems,enjoy coding.

Comment: i have always find through findviewbyid() instead of row.findviewbyid() this is the first ever time can you make me understand why to find through row method?

Comment: @KhurramIqbal Because rowView is viewGroup of textView,i.e. textView is chiled  view of  rowView  not of activity layout.

Comment: @giru: lols i'm also talking about the row. i think u didnt understand my point let me elaborate. I'm saying each and every time i've fetched any child element through findviewbyid while using my custom arrayadapter even in this very same project i've many other listviews and i'm finding row child through findviewbyid instead of row.findviewbyid. Than why that working on rest of the listview custom adapter class! than of here.Nnow i guess i'm pretty clear

Comment: @KhurramIqbal  Is  item layout of all listviews same or different?

Answer (score 0):

YOu may be get null value from position on array here:

```
        int pos = position+4;

        String name = Names[pos];
```

for imediate solution you can add something like this:

```
int pos = position+4;

String name = ""+Names[pos];
```

so you dont have null value and dont get nullpointer,.

now if you want proper solution of getting nul value then debug applicaiton and check the valus of **array** and **name** every time that executes.
Good Luck..

Comment: the problem is still there :/

Answer (score 0):

I also faced like a problem **even though my View id is correct**. But finally I changed the id and clean the project then build once. It is worked correctly.